# how to handle resume and pause events on android L Appcelerator

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

How can I handle resume and pause events on android L in appcelerator?
I can't fire local notification when the app is on background and I have some issues when the app resumes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the second half of your question explains why you need these events, but the short answer is; you can't. You can set the [onPause](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Activity-property-onPause) callback for an individual Window or TabGroup activity, but Android does not have an app-wide notice of pause and resume.

Answer (score 0):

Pause and resume event work differently on iOS and Android. On android pause and resumed events are associated with activities not with the app.So it is not possible to tell from those events if an app goes in background or it wakes up from background.This is not unique to Titanium Android apps, but an issue with JAVA Android apps as well.People have found workaround though with custom make modules though. Their solution is something like this.

Ti.App.addEventListener('resumed', onResumed);
Ti.App.addEventListener('paused', onPaused);

```
if (OS_ANDROID) {
    var platformTools = require('bencoding.android.tools').createPlatform(),
        wasInForeGround = true;

    setInterval(function() {
        var isInForeground = platformTools.isInForeground();

        if (wasInForeGround !== isInForeground) {
            Ti.App.fireEvent(isInForeground ? 'resumed' : 'paused');

            wasInForeGround = isInForeground;
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

You can find details [here](http://www.tidev.io/2014/01/28/paused-resumed-events-on-android/)

Answer (score 0):

For android you can use callback of window. example

```
       Ti.Android.currentActivity.onStart = function() {
            //forground
        };
        Ti.Android.currentActivity.onStop = function() {
            //App entered in Background
        };
```